# azure bicep passing one module output to another module input using array

Tags: azure-bicep

I have a VNET module and getting output as

```
output subnetids array = [for (name, i) in subnets :{
  subnets : virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[i].id
}]
```

and one module for creating app service plan and getting output as

```
output servicePlanIds array = [for (name, i) in serviceplans :{
  ids : appServicePlan[i].id
}]
```

Now, I would like to combine both these array outputs and trying to create two web apps: I am unable to find a way to pass values to serverfarmid and virtualnetworksubnetid. Please help.

```
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-01' = [for webappName in webappNames: {
  name: WebappName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: serviplanIds.output.appServicePlan[].id
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnetids.output.subnets[0].id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: true
      http20Enabled: true
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: why not using `for (webappName, i) in webappNames` as well ?

Comment: I have no problem naming webapp by using params. But struggling to find a way to loop the subnet id's and server farm id's from the output of their respective modules.

Comment: how do you know which subnet is for which webapp for example ? could you share a little bit more of your bicep files please (to understadn the orchestration and how your parameters are defined) ?